# How to make standard WPF spellchecker recognize abbreviations like e.g., i.e

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary, spell-checking

I have an app that uses a Richtextbox for editing documents.  I cannot figure out how to cause spellchecker to recognize common abbreviations like "e.g." or "i.e.".  When I right-click on the abbreviations the list will show the abbreviations, but the spellchecker still underlines (with red) the abbreviations.  If I try to add the abbreviation to the my dictionary it is ignored, I suppose since the abbreviation actually is already listed in the WPF dictionary.  Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: A custom dictionary is your obvious route. There are some potential pitfalls. http://www.pixata.co.uk/2018/05/23/enabling-spell-checking-in-wpf-and-using-a-custom-dictionary-across-the-application/

Comment: Custom dictionary is already implemented, as I mentioned trying to add the abbreviations to this dictionary fails due to the internal dictionary already containing the abbreviations.